# Javascript: Correct way to inherit properties/methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am recently being converted from a C#er to a Javascripter. I have a fundamental query of how I should be designing my "classes" as far as common properties/methods are concerned.

Below, I want to have "id" as a common property along with start and stop methods. Surely. the "id" will be different across instances of MyDerivedClass. There could be MyOtherDerivedClass which needs to be inherit from MyBaseClass, so wanted this "id" to be a common property in the base. May be its my thinking is what I need to get right, please let me know how I could redesign this the way its done typically in Javascript.

```
var MyBaseClass = function(id){
MyBaseClass.prototype.id = id;    
MyBaseClass.prototype.start = function(){
    console.log('Starting item %s', this.id);
    //...//
    console.log('Started item %s', this.id);
};

MyBaseClass.prototype.stop = function(){
    console.log('Stopping item %s', this.id);
    //...//
    console.log('Stopped item %s', this.id);
};
};

var MyDerivedClass = function(id){    
    MyDerivedClass.prototype.connected = false;
    MyDerivedClass.prototype.id = id; //?????
};

inherit(MyDerivedClass, jsDialTone.common.items.DynamicItem);

// This is the inherit method
var inherit = function(child, base){
var Dummy = function(){};
Dummy.prototype = base.prototype;
child.prototype = new Dummy();
child.prototype.constructor = child;
};

var d1 = new MyDerivedClass('D1');
expect(d1.id).toBe('D1'); // passes
var d2 = new MyDerivedClass('D2');
expect(d1.id).toBe('D1'); // fails, since I modified the prototype.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `d2.id = 'D2'` (but really `this.id = id` in the constructor); and do the same for the `connected` flag.

The id value is *not* shared between instances and is therefor *not* fitting to use a shared property on the [[Prototype]].

In general, [[Prototype]] objects should *not* be modified in their respective constructor-functions because it usually does not make sense: it is akin to setting a static (or "shared") variable in a C# or Java constructor.

Comment: I guess it came from few readings I ran across, probably I did not get them correctly. But say if this code is part of some libary and a user of this library does, var instance = Object.create(MyDerivedClass.prototype), the instance should have a property called id or connected ya? Or they should be actually doing Object.create(MyDerivedClass) instead. I mean, my thinking was, "id" and "connected" were like "common" for all instances, sure their values are different but still all instances have an "id". Hence the prototype was the place for it.

Comment: Using the prototype (whatever that is to be, it need not be F.prototype) with Object.create is correct. It usually doesn't make sense to pass a function directly to Object.created, as one generally doesn't do `MyDerviedClass.thisIsToBeAPrototypeProperty = ..`. Object.create is arguably more prototype-OO-ish than setting the prototype property of the function invoked with `new`, but has the same effect on the [[prototype]] of the newly created object.

Comment: `var MyBaseClass = function(id){
this.id = id;    
};`


`var MyDerivedClass = function(id){    
    this.connected = false;
    MyBaseClass.call(this, id);
};`


`inherit(MyDerivedClass, jsDialTone.common.items.DynamicItem);` 

Should this be a right fix then?

Comment: That looks a lot better, yes. Note how the use of Create.object (as shown by TheSportBaron) can cut out the extra 'inherit' implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer should solve your problem, here's a bit more.

```
function MyBaseClass(id) {
    this.id = id;
}

MyBaseClass.prototype.start = function() {
    console.log('Starting item ', this.id);
    //...//
    console.log('Started item ', this.id);
};

MyBaseClass.prototype.stop = function() {
    console.log('Stopping item ', this.id);
    //...//
    console.log('Stopped item ', this.id);    
};

function MyDerivedClass(id) {
    MyBaseClass.call(this, id);
}

MyDerivedClass.prototype = Object.create(MyBaseClass.prototype);


var base = new MyBaseClass(1);

var derived = new MyDerivedClass(2);

base.start();

derived.start();
```

This should print out in the console:

`Starting item  1`

`Started item  1`

`Starting item  2`

`Started item  2`

- You'll create the class MyBaseClass, then set methods on it's prototype.
- Then, you'll create a MyDerivedClass which uses the .call() method, which will run the MyBaseClass function, but it will set the `this` explicitly with the first argument.
- Then, you set MyDerivedClass's prototype to MyBaseClass's prototype with Object.create().

Check these links out for more reference:

[Prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

[The .call() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

JavaScript is weird.